# How to include multiple keys and values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I need some help with a JSON post request, I need to post an array of fields with multiple ids and values. Posting one id and value works but I can't figure out how to include multiple field IDs in this request.

Here is my code:

```
$appointment = $acuity->request('/appointments', array(
'method' => 'POST',
'data' => array(
'firstName' => 'Bob',
'lastName' => 'Burger',
'email' => 'bob@example.org',
'datetime' => '2016-04-26T19:00:00-0700',
'appointmentTypeID' => 5020,
'fields' => array(
  array(
    'id' => 4,  // Custom field ID 4
    'value' => '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue',
    'id' => 5,  // Custom field ID 5
    'value' => '5550 Somewhere St.'
  )
)
)
));
```

Comment: your 'fields' array should contain multiple arrays, themselves containing 'id' and 'value'. So in your example there'd be two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the intent is for this to use nested arrays, like so:

```
'fields' => array(
  array(
    'id' => 4,  // Custom field ID 4
    'value' => '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue',
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 5,  // Custom field ID 5
    'value' => '5550 Somewhere St.'
  )
)
```